# Storing an arrayList of student objects in 1st element of a 2 element Object array

Tags: java, android

So I have a 2 element Object array in which 1st element should store an arrayList of student Objects and then pass the Object array as argument to another for example say "X" method And now accessing the arrayList elements from that Object array 1st element and add it to another list.
  what I have done is, In my code I have

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
//And then I create student objects
//I have a For loop
 Student s = new Student( //add student object)
//Add student objects to list
students.add(s);
//Now for loop is done and now I assign Object array 1st element to students
 o[1]=students;
//pass the object array to a method
MainActivity.x(o); //This is from postExecute
//Method declaration in MAINACTIVITY class
//In main Program class List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>(); is declared
public void x(Object[] res)
{
  studentList.add((Student)res[1]);

}
```

The problem is was getting a class cast exception. I think there is something that I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use a [`Map`-implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (e.g. [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html))?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code:

(1) You are assigning a `List<Student>` and passing to `x` method, so you can't typecast to `Student` i.e., you can only cast to List

(2) **array indexes** start with **0**, so assign the 1st element using index 0, not with index 1

The code is shown below with inline comments:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
Student s = new Student();
students.add(s);

Object[] objects = new Object[2];
o[0]=students;//assigning list

MainActivity.x(o);

public void x(Object[] res) {
  List<Student> studentsList = (List<Student>)res[0];//typecast to List only
  //studentList.add();
}
```

Also, as a side note, I strongly suggest you to **name the variables properly** so that they can be easily readable and the bugs can be easily detected i.e. if you name the variables like `s`, `o`, it will not be very clear for others to follow your code (so, name them starting with smaller case like `student`, `object`, etc..).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `ClassCastException` because of your assignment `o[1]=students`. This places the `List<Student>` into the array, whereas the method `x` expects a `Student` in that position.

I think what you need is the following:

```
public void x(Object[] res) {
    studentList.add(((List<Student>)res[1]).get(0));
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an out of memory error...what to do? And it is particularly pointing at line where I did Student s = new Student(\\fields of student objects)

Comment: @HariKumar ...I don't know? OOMs can happen anywhere, anytime where you allocate. Post a second question with more code concerning your allocation, stacktrace and a real, working code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

first of all there is several more nicer approaches to what you want 
but the error in this code is

```
public void x(Object[] res) 
{
 studentList.addAll((List<Student>)res[1]);
//you are passing an array list not an object that is why is is causing a cast exception

}
```

also please show the initialization of o
I would suggest creating a class that contains arraylist of student and any other element you want to pass and pass this object to the method

Like

```
class DataStudents {
 public ArrayList<Student> students;
 public String anyOtherData;
}
```

and pass it to

```
 public void x(DataStudents res) 
{
 studentList.addAll(res.students);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an out of memory error...what to do? And it is particularly pointing at line where I did Student s = new Student(\\fields of student objects)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting to Student in the last cast to ArrayList.